# I'm assigned task of automating data flow from Access DB to Oracle DB on a monthly basis

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ms-access, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a monthly snapshot table "A1" in Access Db which gets loaded automatically. I am required to have this data available for reporting purposes in Oracle DB "table B1". right now, I am manually exporting excel file from Access table "A1" and importing in Oracle DB "table B1" each month which is not ideal. I want to automate this process of flowing Data into oracle DB as soon as our Access Db gets loaded by monthly data. can anyone help and suggest what would be an ideal way to achieve this automation?

regards
Qazi

I have created table "b1" in oracle DB that holds data from A1 presently. so data structure of A1=B1. I need help with automating the rest of the process.

Comment: Easiest and most foolproof is to install the Oracle ODBC driver into your computer if it's not already there. Then in Access go to External data ODBC and map the table into your Access DB (do not import the data). Now you can write an Append query in Access that appends all the data in A to table B.  After that you can make a script that does that and then flushes the data from table A to get ready for the next time.

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged for Google Cloud Dataflow?  I'm sure it's possible to use that to move the data.  But that would seem like a pretty unusual architecture unless there is more context (i.e. you're trying to tie in to an existing data flow that loads the Oracle data warehouse).

Comment: @chris thanks for the comment. I have ODBC driver configured on my PC which is all fine. however, after creating append query, I am struggling to come up with a script that schedules the flow of data from Access DB to Oracle DB.

Comment: In other words, you want to *automatically* run this script at some interval?   Is your PC always on that it can run it at the right time?  Assuming yes, then Access has no built-in way of running a script (macro) at a certain time, but Windows has a Task Scheduler that can do it. You will have to clone your Access DB, drop the Access tables, map the tables in from the original Access DB, add an "Exit from Access" command to the end of your macro, rename it AUTOEXEC, then create a PowerShell script to invoke that Access & add it to Task Scheduler